# python manipulate columns remove substring

Tags: python, csv, numpy, pandas

I have a csv that I am reading into a data frame. I am then using a series to modify a specific column of the csv. this column contains the date and time. I essentially want to remove the time from the column. The column looks like this

```
0      7/28/2015 14:31
1       7/28/2015 8:13
2      7/28/2015 16:16
3      7/28/2015 16:18
4       7/27/2015 9:54
5       7/27/2015 9:52
```

I split the columns

```
s = df['Work Info Date'].str.split(' ')
0      [7/28/2015, 14:31]
1       [7/28/2015, 8:13]
2      [7/28/2015, 16:16]
3      [7/28/2015, 16:18]
4       [7/27/2015, 9:54]
5       [7/27/2015, 9:52]
```

When i try to del the time element using del it just deletes the index

```
del s[1]
0      [7/28/2015, 14:31]
2      [7/28/2015, 16:16]
3      [7/28/2015, 16:18]
4       [7/27/2015, 9:54]
5       [7/27/2015, 9:52]
```

My ultimate goal is to delete the time from this column **and** join it back to the spreadsheet.

```
0      7/28/2015
1       7/28/2015
2      7/28/2015
3      7/28/2015
4       7/27/2015
5       7/27/2015
```

**Spreadsheet:**

```
Incident ID,Submitter,Time Spent,Work Info Date
INC000004294045,Bob,,7/28/2015 14:31
INC000004301664,Janice,,7/28/2015 8:13
INC000004301813,Robert,,7/28/2015 16:16
INC000004301813,Alex,,7/28/2015 16:18
```

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np




df = pd.read_csv('output2.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')
s = df['Work Info Date'].str.split(' ')

s.name = 'Work Info Date'
del s[1]
s



#del df['Work Info Date']
#df.join(s)
#time_report = pd.pivot_table(df, index=["Submitter", "Work Info Date"], values=["Time Spent"], aggfunc = [np.sum], fill_value=0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get vectorized access to select a column by using `.str` again:

```
>>> df["Work Info Date"].str.split()
0    [7/28/2015, 14:31]
1     [7/28/2015, 8:13]
2    [7/28/2015, 16:16]
3    [7/28/2015, 16:18]
dtype: object
>>> df["Work Info Date"].str.split().str[0]
0    7/28/2015
1    7/28/2015
2    7/28/2015
3    7/28/2015
dtype: object
>>> df["Just_the_Date"] = df["Work Info Date"].str.split().str[0]
>>> df
       Incident ID Submitter  Time Spent   Work Info Date Just_the_Date
0  INC000004294045       Bob         NaN  7/28/2015 14:31     7/28/2015
1  INC000004301664    Janice         NaN   7/28/2015 8:13     7/28/2015
2  INC000004301813    Robert         NaN  7/28/2015 16:16     7/28/2015
3  INC000004301813      Alex         NaN  7/28/2015 16:18     7/28/2015
```

Where you might want to convert the date to a column of dates and not just a string, but that's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Series.apply` , and `datetime.strptime()` and `datetime.strftime()` , to first parse the date-time as a datetime object and then convert it back to string in your required format. Code -

```
df['Work Info Date'] = df['Work Info Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
```

This can have the advantage that you can convert the date to whichever format you want.

Example/Demo -

```
In [3]: df = pd.read_csv('a.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
       Incident ID Submitter  Time Spent   Work Info Date
0  INC000004294045       Bob         NaN  7/28/2015 14:31
1  INC000004301664    Janice         NaN   7/28/2015 8:13
2  INC000004301813    Robert         NaN  7/28/2015 16:16
3  INC000004301813      Alex         NaN  7/28/2015 16:18

In [6]: import datetime

In [7]: df['Work Info Date'] = df['Work Info Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))

In [8]: df
Out[8]:
       Incident ID Submitter  Time Spent Work Info Date
0  INC000004294045       Bob         NaN     07/28/2015
1  INC000004301664    Janice         NaN     07/28/2015
2  INC000004301813    Robert         NaN     07/28/2015
3  INC000004301813      Alex         NaN     07/28/2015
```